# Finding Threshold to Binarize a Correlation Matrix

Tags: python, matplotlib, correlation, threshold

I've created a correlation matrix using Matplotlib, and would like to set a threshold, so that I can make all the values above the threshold 1, and everything below it 0. My aim is to create an adjacency matrix, so that I can apply different centrality measures to the graph that is created.

My question is, how exactly do I fix that threshold? Is it an arbitrary value, or is there some method that has to be used to find the threshold value from the correlation matrix. Forgive me, I'm quite a beginner when it comes to correlation matrices.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you are looking for how to get the threshold value using the correlation matrix, you might want to post this question on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com).